# where case when in clause statement

Tags: sql-server, subquery, case-when

I need a SQL query having WHERE CASE WHEN statement with a in list. I am not sure what part of my query is wrong,

First I need to make a KEY out of coldelist and IDD,IDP and then since my codelists' lenght are 5 or 6 so need to use CASE WHEN to check if their length are 5 or 6 then search in separate lists (each almost 200 or more) because my aim is to compare some tables' data using EXCEPT

My SQL statement is like:

```
SELECT
    codelist = CASE 
                  WHEN LEN(codelist) = 5
                     THEN CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(codelist, 1, 5), IDD), IDP) 
                  WHEN LEN(codelist) = 6
                     THEN CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(codelist, 1, 6), IDD), IDP) 
                  ELSE codelist 
               END,
    codelist 
FROM
    [table1]
WHERE
    (codelist = CASE 
                   WHEN LEN(codelist) = 5  
                      THEN (SELECT 'FEV00', 'FEV64', 'FEV97', 'FEV90')
                   WHEN LEN(codelist) = 6   
                      THEN (SELECT 'FEV208', 'FEV227', 'FEV308', 'FEV326')
                END)
EXCEPT
SELECT
     ....
```

Comment: You'll need to provide some sample data and your table schemas if you'd like some help.

Comment: Please edit your question to include some sample data and expected results. You can't do `where Something = (subquery)` like that, so you're probably not really looking for a WHERE-CASE-WHEN solution either.

Comment: there are different tables with a column codelist, I need a query to check differences between these tables base on a list of codelist , 
These codelist have either 5 or 6 characters so i need to use WHERE-CASE-WHEN , if Len(coldelist)=5 search in a 5 character lists or Len(coldelist)=6 to search in 6 character lists